# Unwanted Asynchronous Reset

Tags: asynchronous, vhdl, reset, xilinx, vivado

I have written the following VHDL code with the assumption that it will generate a counter with a synchronous reset! however, when I looked at the elaborated design in Vivado 2020.2, the counter has an ASYNCHRONOUS reset! The process should not get evaluated without seeing the rising/falling edges of the clock! How did the tool infer an asynchronous reset?!

PS. count is defined as an unsigned signal (not std_logic_vector)

Any explanation is greatly appreciated!

```
process(clk)
    begin
        if rst='1' then
            count <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            count <= count + 1;
        end if;
end process;
```

Comment: That's not the RTL form for a synchronous reset, nor an asynchronous reset without rst in the sensitivity list. For an example with a synchronous reset `if rising_edge(clk) then if rst = '1' then count <= (others => '0'); else count <= count + 1; end if; end if;`. See UG901 VHDL Sequential Logic, Initializing Registers Example Two (VHDL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesis tools generally ignore the sensitivity list, and create the logic from design patterns in the code. In your code, the `rst` branch overrides the clock branch, hence it creates an asynchronous reset. In addition, the reset is not reliant on `clk`.

To create a synchronous reset, the `rst` branch should be inside the clock branch as the reset should only occur on a clock edge.

```vhdl
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    count <= count + 1;

    if rst = '1' then 
      count <= (others => '0');
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```